# How to call Data Integration when interaction is involved?

Tags: web-services, integration, terminology, data-integration

First let's define Data Integration: "combine data from different sources and present users with a unified view"
I interpret data sources as databases with tables, files and more. 
My question: What do you call it when, on the functional level, extra interactions are needed?

Example: take for example a webservice in which you first need to provide your country code, after which the weather results are returned. And in this case I need a weather report attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like simple data integration.  You could label it as such and it would be clear.  If you must, you could classify it as a subset of data integration called an [Edge Data Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_data_integration).

From Wikipedia:

> An edge data integration is an implementation of data integration technology undertaken in an ad hoc or tactical fashion. This is also sometimes referred to as point-to-point integration because it connects two types of data directly to serve a narrow purpose.

They go on to define examples of Edge Data Integration, one of which seems similar to your weather case:

> [An] Example of [an] edge data integration project might be combining data from a weather Web site, a shipping company's Web site, and a company's internal logistics database to track shipments and estimated arrival times of packages